# Error when Starting Typesafe Reactive Activator

Tags: playframework, frameworks, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I want to use the Typesafe Reactive Activator to create a Play Framework project on my Windows 8.1.

I download the activator, extract it, and run the BAT file as instructed.

The command line opens up and I get the following message:

The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\.activator\1.3.2\activator
config.txt.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\.activator\activatorconfig
.txt.

I have tried adding to the PATH variable, the commands "activator" and "activator ui" from the command line and everything else I can find.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to "solve" it.

Turns out those messages don't stop the execution, so after a while the activator opened.

Still don't know why those files are missing and what is supposed to be on them, but my problem is solved for now.

If someone knows about those files, I would want to know it please